# Rotation transformation matrix, question on $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Does anyone know how $\sin$ and $\cos$ contribute to the transformed $x', y'$ coordinates?  From elementary geometry it's my understanding if a circle's $r = 1$, then $\cos(\theta)$ represents the $x$ component of the right triangle, while $\sin(\theta)$ represents the $y$.
Perhaps this is something obvious I'm overlooking.

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
x' \\
y' \\
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
\end{array}\right]$$

After the matrix product:

$$\begin{cases}x' = x \cos (\theta) + y \sin (\theta)\\
y' = -x \sin (\theta) + y \cos (\theta)\end{cases}$$

Comment: How they contribute ? But you have the expressions, what more do you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have signs of the sines wrong (EDIT: if you refer to a counterclockwise rotation). The matrix for a rotation through an angle $\theta$ is

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$$

You can see this from the fact that a linear tranformation is uniquely determined by what it does to the standard basis vectors (if you don't feel confident about this you should look closer into it). If you consider the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\mathbf{e}_1 = (1,0)$ and $\mathbf{e}_2 = (0,1)$, basic trigonometry will yield that when rotated they become $(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$, as suggested by yourself in your question, and $(-\sin(\theta), \cos(\theta))$. Adding these as columns in the matrix, we get the matrix above.

Comment: This was very helpful.  I understand $e1$ and $cos(\theta),sin(\theta)$  but am having difficulty understanding why $-sin(\theta) cos(\theta)$ is  chosen.   Perhaps I keep associating $sin(\theta)$ to an $y$ component and $cos(\theta)$ to an $x$ component

Comment: Is $(-sin(\theta), cos(\theta))$ used in the matrix such that the 0 degree angle is really at 90 degrees, which would swap orientation of the opposite and adjacent legs of the triangle by 90 degrees.

Comment: Yes, if I understood you correctly, you are right. If you make a sketch, you will get two triangles where one is a 90 degree rotation of the other.